# c++ free(none gpl ) webservice framework

Tags: c++, web-services, free

im looking for good freeware that is not GPL c++ webservices frame work
i have used AXIS2 but it is no good for our needs ,is there any good framework that
can be good and robust like the gSoap for example

Comment: If you don't think GPL counts as "Free" then I'm afraid you are going to have to define the term. Otherwise, people may suggest stuff with equally bad licenses from your perspective.

Comment: The OP is not saying GPL is not free. Just that he wants another framework that is free but not GPL. (The usual reason for wanting this is that he does not want to release his code)

Answer (score 1):

I've used wsdlpull http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/ and it worked.  It is very simple, doesn't generate stubs for you and I'm not sure how it deals with complex data types, but if you need something simple it will do the job.  It is LGPL so you can link closed-source code to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try WSF Staff.

Easy create web services and clients in C++.

Complex types like structures, typedefs, STL containers are supported. WSDL is supported.

Code can be generated by codegen or written manually.

Generated code is compact, light, human readable and easy to understand.

License: Open source (Apache License 2.0).

Project is based on Axis2/C (wrapped most most used Axis2/C features into C++ code, also have many additional features). Ported to Windows, Linux.

**Project page:**

http://code.google.com/p/staff/

**Example:** How to create Calculator service:

http://code.google.com/p/staff/wiki/ExampleCalculatorServiceWindows

**Example:** How to create Calculator client:

http://code.google.com/p/staff/wiki/ExampleCalculatorClientWindows